# Serialize Hashset of enum in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, enums, hashset

I want to serialize in MongoDB, member Engines (HashSet of enum) as string to see the name as string and not a number 
The class is :

```
public class EnginesPerFile
{
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public HashSet<EngineType> Engines { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map like this :

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EnginesPerFile>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.MapIdField(c => c.FileId);
                cm.MapMember(c => c.Engines).SetSerializer(new EnumSerializer<EngineType>(BsonType.String));
            });
```

But i get an error:

```
Value type of serializer is EngineType and does not match member type System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[Playground.Model.EngineType, Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

Parameter name: serializer.

How can i serialize hashset of enum in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by writing custom Serializer:  (EngineType can be a generic T)

```
 public class MyHashSetSerializer : SerializerBase<HashSet<EngineType>>
{
    private readonly IBsonSerializer _serializer =
        BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(EngineType));

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, HashSet<EngineType> value)
    {
        var set = (HashSet<EngineType>)value;

        context.Writer.WriteStartDocument();           
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var element in set)
        {

            context.Writer.WriteName($"[{i}]");
            context.Writer.WriteString(element.ToString());
        }
        context.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    public override HashSet<EngineType> Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<EngineType>();

        context.Reader.ReadStartDocument();
        while (context.Reader.ReadBsonType() != 0)
        {
            context.Reader.SkipName();
            var element =
                (EngineType)_serializer.Deserialize(context, args);              
            set.Add(element);
        }
        context.Reader.ReadEndDocument();

        return set;
    }
}
```

And then i register class map like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EnginesPerFile>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.MapIdField(c => c.FileId);
                cm.MapMember(c => c.Engines).SetSerializer(new MyHashSetSerializer());
            });
```